# Delphi: WSALookupServiceNext, get device detection time

Tags: delphi, bluetooth, winsock2

I am working on a script to detect device arrival time using bluetooth.

The  problem is `WSALookupServiceBegin` takes up to 7 seconds to scan nearby devices, so **device detection time limits to scanning start time** (This makes detection time doesn't accurate so much). I've searched a lot but it seems that scan time can't be changed.

Can I get the time that device is founded during scanning time?

Comment: I don't understand the question. Are you worried about the blocking during the scan?

Comment: No, I can't get exact time device is found and arrived to that particular position because scanning time is too long.